# Why is S == S[::-1] faster than looping?

Tags: python, string, performance, palindrome

Why is the pythonic way of checking if a string, `S`, is a palindrome -- `S == S[::-1]` -- faster than the following implementation?

```
i = 0
j = len(S) - 1
while i < j:
    if S[i] != S[j]:
        return False
    i += 1
    j -= 1
return True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Python code is only compiled to bytecode, which is then interpreted. That's going to be a lot slower than creating a new reversed string in C code, then comparing the string to another string with more C code.

Note that both algorithms are essentially O(N) complexity; the Python code executes at most 1/2 N iterations, and the string reversal version makes at most 2 N iterations, but asymptotically speaking that doesn't make a difference.

Since both algorithms are O(N) linear approaches, what matters then is their constant cost, how much time each iteration takes. That fixed cost is *vastly* lower for `s == s[::-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

`S == S[::-1]` is going to be fast in worst cases because everything is running in C for this case, which is going to be lightning quick compared to a Python based loop. The only advantage of your version is that it won't wait for the creation of a reversed string before it can starts comparing, hence in those situations<sup>*</sup> for huge strings `S == S[::-1]` will be actually slow.

We can improve `S == S[::-1]` a little bit if instead of comparing the whole we take a slice of first half and second half of the string and compare first half with reversed version of second half.

```
def fast_half(S):
    length = len(S)
    half = length/2
    first, last = half + (length % 2), half
    return S[:first] == S[last:][::-1]

def fast_simple(S):
    return S == S[::-1]
```

Let's compare them:

```
>>> S = 'A' * 10**5
>>> %timeit fast_simple(S)
10000 loops, best of 3: 88.7 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half(S)
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.1 µs per loop
>>> S = 'A' * 10**6
>>> %timeit fast_simple(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 601 µs per loop
```

We can make `fast_half` slightly fast by taking a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typememoryview) of the first half, for second half it is not possible because memoryviews don't support extended slicing. And also they only work with `str`(`bytes` in Python 3) and `bytearrays`.

```
def fast_half_memoryview(S):
    length = len(S)
    half = length/2
    first, last = half + (length % 2), half
    return memoryview(S)[:first] == S[last:][::-1]

>>> S = 'A' * 10**5
>>> %timeit fast_half_memoryview(S)
10000 loops, best of 3: 46 µs per loop
>>> S = 'A' * 10**6
>>> %timeit fast_half_memoryview(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 523 µs per loop
>>> S = 'A' * 10**7
>>> %timeit fast_half(S)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half_memoryview(S)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit fast_simple(S)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.3 ms per loop
```

For tiny strings `S == S[::-1]` is the best of the lot:

```
>>> S = 'A' * 10
>>> %timeit fast_half(S)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 721 ns per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half_memoryview(S)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_simple(S)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 353 ns per loop
>>> %timeit func(S)  # OP's code
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop
```

---

<sup>*</sup> When creation of reversed string or slicing can slow us down:

```
>>> S = 'A' * 10**6 + 'a'
>>> %timeit fast_simple(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 976 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 566 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_half_memoryview(S)
1000 loops, best of 3: 523 µs per loop
>>> %timeit func(S)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 382 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a great benchmarking, but every time I ran it your function is slightly **slower** than `s == s[::-1]`. I also tried to change the order of the execution (run your function first) and it still provides the same results!

```
import timeit

def is_pali1(s):
    s = str(s)
    return s == s[::-1]


def is_pali2(S):
    S = str(S)
    i = 0
    j = len(S) - 1
    while i < j:
        if S[i] != S[j]:
            return False
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    return True

res = timeit.repeat("for x in range(99999900,100000000): is_pali1(x)", "from __main__ import is_pali1", number=100000)
print "is_pali1", sum(res)/len(res)
res = timeit.repeat("for x in range(99999900,100000000): is_pali2(x)", "from __main__ import is_pali2", number=100000)
print "is_pali2", sum(res)/len(res)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
is_pali1 4.37230348587
is_pali2 4.67844009399
```

Note that I modified the number into a string in both functions: `s = str(s)` so that shouldn't bias the results. **Tested on Python 2.7.6.**

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry but I feel like I'm missing something... (this code *is* using timeit) can you please explain?

Comment: I need more caffeine. I missed that you used `timeit()`. So why not use the `repeat()` option of `timeit.timeit()` then, rather than run the same trial 10 times in a loop?

Comment: Your 'palindrome' is also *very small*. You want to test with larger strings (or numbers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used bigger numbers to your request. Still shows the same results (post updated). Perhaps you meant *really* bigger? As for the `repeat()` option - thanks for pointing it out - I'm just getting familiar with timeit - I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: You are not using larger numbers. You still use `x` in the range from 0 to 9. Your outer loop *doesn't play here*. Testing the function with *one character input* is hardly testing for performance differences.

Comment: @alfasin I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing! :)

Comment: When I use a 100k random string to test the functions, I see a 100+ fold performance difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The `number` argument to `timeit.repeat()`'s is set to 100K which means it's running 100K cycles per every `i` in the range (to my understanding).

Comment: Look at the argument to the function under test: `for x in range(10): is_pali1(x)`. That's `x` from the `for` loop, which iterates over `range(10)`. `i` doesn't come into this at all.

Comment: As for the length of the strings (which is 9 characters in this example) - It's longer than an average word in almost any language - so I believe it should be sufficient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The definition of the *number* argument from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html): "The argument is the *number* of times through the loop, defaulting to one million." (but maybe I got it wrong - please correct if so!) The outer for-loop probably confused you - I can remove it altogether. The number of times this code is tested is the range of `i` multiply by 100K (every timeit iteration runs the function 100K times).

Comment: @AdamSmith can you please be more specific ?

Comment: @alfasin: the length of the strings is **one digit**. `x` is one of `0`, `1`, `2`, through to `9`. `is_pali1(9)` is then trying to figure out if `'9'` is a palindrome. You are not testing with longer strings here. That's my point, you are testing how fast the two function are for strings of length 1, which is rather pointless.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying... there are two for-loops, I need to change the other one...

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah you're right, I updated the answer with the relevant results! Thanks for being patient with me! :)